# How to check a string contains only en-us keyboard characters?

Tags: c#

How to check a string, whether it contains only keyboard characters, i.e, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and all special characters (like ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><,./';][=-) that are available only in a US Enlish keyboard. i.e, the user should be able to type the string from the keyboard without typing any ALT keys.
I am not familiar with Regex to filter the string that satisfies my requirement.

Comment: Did you try pass them into `Regex`?

Comment: What's the problem with the linked Regex question?

Comment: Perhaps OP isn't good with RegEx (even simple ones) and prefers not using them, which makes totally sense

Comment: @Cid: That may be the case, but saying so - with more details - would be a lot more useful than "This or others did not help me." If we don't know in what *way* existing answers don't help, it's likely that any other answer we offer may be rejected as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet that *"doesn't help"* probably because the linked question is about alphanum only, not the whole English keyboard mapping. But yes, I know, that's a little effort to do to adapt a simple RegEx to fit OP's case

Comment: @Cid: Again, *maybe* that's the case. But really the OP needs to tell us, otherwise it's just a guess. I would certainly be reluctant to try to help without more detail.

Comment: Yes, I am not familiar with Regex to filter the string that satisfies my requirement. i,e, the characters that are available in an English keyboard.

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen a UK user could argue that a real English keyboard has very different special characters. There's a [Wikipedia article on the differences between UK and US keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards). What you posted looks like the characters in *some* US keyboard layouts

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen Just add all the characters you want to support to the regex collection. For example `^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().,\-+]*$ ` Just note that some characters (like `-`) need to be escaped by an `\\`

Comment: I accept I should not have told that other answers didn't help me. It is meaningless. since they are about alphanum only. My requirement is the same,  i,e, the characters that are available on an English keyboard (either by pressing SHIFT or not)

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen what are you trying to do? This sounds like an XY Problem. What is the actual problem you want to solve? Are you trying to enforce some kind of password character restriction? Anyone can add any keyboard layout to any machine (PC, phone) at any time and switch between them. Even in a single country there are multiple layouts, especially the US.

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen `My requirement is the same, i,e, the characters that are available on an English keyboard` in that case you need to accept £ as well

Comment: The actual requirement is, I want to get string inputs from user, and the inputs should be only the normal characters, that are available in an en-us keyboard.

Comment: Does this '£' character present in an English keyboard. I don't think so. I may be wrong. I don't need that  £ character.

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen It's available in English-UK layout

Comment: If so, I must edit my question.

Comment: You'd be wrong, and I already posted a link to the differences between layouts. Again, what's the *real* problem? What you describe is the attempted solution. Do you want to sanitize input? If you want to restrict password characters, you'd be introducing a *vulnerability*. Both US (NIST) and UK (NSCS) authorities [warn *against* restricting password input.](https://www.troyhunt.com/passwords-evolved-authentication-guidance-for-the-modern-era/)

Comment: It is certainly not a password. It is a typing app. I want users to type the normal characters. it is a windows store app (uwp).

Comment: Which has no problems with any kind of character. Why introduce such arbitrary restrictions? And even in the UK you'd have to allow €. It's a common character even if it needs the Alt key

Comment: @Mark Baijens I prefer, to accept only the required characters manually by regex, (^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*().,\-+]*$ ) as you have mentioned. I accept this as an answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I have edited my question, I am not focusing UK or other keyboard layouts. I want to get the characters that are available in the en-us keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codepoint for immediately (without Alt) available characters in English-US keyboard layout are between 32 to 126.

On C#, you can skip Regex entirely by doing

```
input.All(c=> c >= 32 && c <= 126);
```

It simply verifies that all `char` inside the `input` match the range. Technically, due to the [character encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=netcore-3.1), a single Unicode character can involve several `char`, but as long as you're checking that *all* of them are inside the range, it's fine.

Or if you want regex :

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\u0020-\u007E]*$"); //true on empty string

Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\u0020-\u007E]+$"); //must be at least one character
```

It's the same thing, `^` specify the match must start from the beginning of the string, everything inside the bracket specify the range, between 32 to 126, except they're written in hexadecimal, `*` allow any length, + allow 1 to more, and `$` specify the match must cover until the end of the string.

Note that users of any other layout (English-UK, International English, etc) will be very annoyed with your limitation.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the last line of your answer. The above code rejects the input from the users of other layout. I will be correct if the input string allowed by this code can be typed by any other layout (English-UK, International English, etc).